# Jersey Client not requesting webservice

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have a tricky question about Jersey Rest client. I have the following code:

```
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
    ....
    // Building the url and servicePath
    service = service.path(servicePath);
    service = service.queryParam("user",newUser.getIdUser());
    log.info("Service: " + service.toString());
    ClientResponse response = service.accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE).get(ClientResponse.class);
    String responseHTML = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

This code works perfectly in my development machine (my workstation), but when I upload the war to the acceptance server it doesn't work at all. The url for the webservice is perfectly formed, as I can see it from the logfile, but the .get() call does not call the WS at all. And, it only happens on the public server.

Furthermore, if I copy the url from the logfile and access it through a web browser, it works perfectly.

Any idea on what is going on?

Thanks,
Cris.

PS: In both machines, development and acceptance, I have installed the same version of the Apache Tomcat.

Comment: I guess you are certain there are no networking restrictions from your acceptance server?

Comment: Yup, none. Indeed, I can access to all the webservices through Chrome's Postman extension on the machine.